# Decomposition of function of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, functions, bounded-variation

Suppose we have $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which is of bounded variation. I would like to show that it can be presented as a sum of left and right continuous functions of bounded variation. Actually I have no idea how to prove that since I think it can't be proven that Jordan decomposition has that properties and direct constructions failed in a way I can't prove them to be right.

Comment: If you can do it for monotone functions you can do it for functions of bounded variation. But every monotone function splits into a continuous one and a saltus function.

Comment: but the function of "jumps" - saltus function ? Is neither left nor right cont.

Comment: This reduces the problem to splitting up monotone saltus functions into right/left continuous ones.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the OP has already solved the problem.  For other readers irritated
by cryptic hints, here are some more details.

As already indicated the problem is really just a refinement of the usual version
one finds:

> **A**. If $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ has bounded variation then $$f(x) = g(x) + s(x)$$ where $g$ is a continuous function of bounded variation
>   and $s$ is a saltus function.

Instead, we ask as well for the saltus part to be split into two nicer pieces:

> **B**. If $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ has bounded variation then $$f(x) = g(x) + s_L(x) + s_R(x)$$ where $g$ is a continuous function of bounded
>   variation and $s_R$ is a right-continuous saltus function and $s_L$ is
>   a left-continuous saltus function.

Let $\{x_n\}$ be the sequence of discontinuities of $f$ and let $a_n=f(x_n)-f(x_n-)$
and $b_n=f(x_n+)-f(x_n)$  be the two one-sided jumps.  (One or both of these are nonzero.)

Write $I(x)=0$ for $x<0$ and $I(x)=1$ for $x\geq 0$.  Write $J(x)=0$ for $x\leq 0$ and $J(x)=1$ for $x> 0$.

Then the saltus function for $f$ is the function

$$s(x)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left\{ a_n I(x-x_n)+ b_nJ(x-x_n)\right\}.$$

The usual textbook proof one can find checks the details to see that $s$ is well-defined, that $f-s$ is continuous and has bounded variation.  And $s$ is a saltus function by definition.  This is probably the standard proof for A.

To get the version B just split the series into two series; one half is a right-continuous saltus $s_R$ and the other is a left-continuous saltus $s_L$.